# Search list contents (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: list, search, infopath

I am investigating whether SharePoint 2013 and InfoPath 2013 can meet our requirements before we invest in it.

One of the things we would be using it for is an approval workflow using a custom InfoPath form with various fields.

One requirement is to be able to search the list for any forms that were submitted and approved with certain field values.

E.g. Form would have a series of checkboxes allowing employees to request a laptop, tablet or phone. Search would allow us to see all submitted forms that have requested a tablet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily create several views for this purpose. For example, one view could be named "laptops" and could display only items where the laptop field was selected. The views would be available to the user via links, so they just click on link for the desired view.

A more advanced solution via search is possible as well, but usually folks go that route when they are trying to consolidate data from multiple lists.

Comment: I think that we will need to use search option, as some of the fields we will need may have up to 20 options to select from. Could you give a quick example of how the search would be implemented?

All I've been able to find looking for information regarding SharePoint searching has mostly related to searching list metadata. Finding information regarding searching list item contents has been difficult.

Comment: To be clear: creating views is a user task that takes  1 to 5 minutes to set up. Customizing search is a power user / developer task that will take quite a bit longer. If you're new to it, set up the views and then post back here what functionality you need that views don't provide.